# Taglist for horizontal widget alignment in RStudio

Tags: html, r, plotly, taglist, htmltools

I have three plotly plots as html widgets which I want to combine into one html. This one does the trick but I want the plots (fig_current, ...) to be saved horizontally after one another and scroll also horizontally and not vertically. How can I do this?

```
htmltools::save_html(htmltools::tagList(fig_current, fig_plant, fig_bl), file ="test.html"))
```